# jquerymobile dynamic check checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I would like to make this example work

http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/m8qyN/1/

to have a select all button

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this way:-

```
$('a[type=button]').click(function() {
    $('#checks  input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked').checkboxradio('refresh');
});
```

On jquery mobile, to check the checkbox you need to use `checkboxradio('refresh')`.

This is the trick, you need to follow to tick the checkbox.

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/m8qyN/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

- http://jsfiddle.net/m8qyN/3/

JS

```
$('#checkAll').on('click', function() {
    $('.checkAllGroup').each(function() {
        var cb = $(this);
        cb.attr('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="Home">
    <div data-role="content">     
test
    <div id="checks" data-role="fieldcontain">
                     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <legend>Pays:</legend>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="reg1" id="checkbox-1a" class="checkAllGroup"/>
                        <label for="checkbox-1a">11</label>

                        <input type="checkbox" name="reg2" id="checkbox-2a" class="checkAllGroup"/>
                        <label for="checkbox-2a">12</label>

                    </fieldset>
                </div>      

        <a type="button" id="checkAll">check</a>


    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use this [setter](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and not a [getter](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

Comment: `The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.` - from http://api.jquery.com/prop/